# Excessive minor garbage collection time

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, garbage

We are having a problem with excessive minor GC time in our, at some point of the day, the the GC start increasing his CPU time the used eden space decreases and it keeps that way for a few hours. So,my question is, why could it be that the GC keeps working after a while if the eden space has already decreased and old gen is not full?

[image]

Also these are the gc logs:

```
35654.202: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 6927699K->158760K(9188864K)] 21881289K->15119270K(31558656K), 0.0641987 secs] [Times: user=0.46 sys=0.01, real=0.06 secs] 
35657.351: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 7265320K->106449K(9102336K)] 22225830K->15079895K(31472128K), 0.0558687 secs] [Times: user=0.42 sys=0.01, real=0.06 secs] 
35660.587: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 7213009K->50739K(9340928K)] 22186455K->15024184K(31710720K), 0.0533427 secs] [Times: user=0.37 sys=0.01, real=0.05 secs] 
35663.747: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7475251K->118288K(9268224K)] 22448729K->15091765K(31638016K), 0.0565819 secs] [Times: user=0.43 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
35666.948: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7542800K->133088K(9520128K)] 22516282K->15106571K(31889920K), 0.0579453 secs] [Times: user=0.42 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
35670.235: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7898080K->460400K(9429504K)] 22871565K->15433884K(31799296K), 0.1234615 secs] [Times: user=0.92 sys=0.00, real=0.12 secs] 
35673.803: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 8225392K->333992K(9727488K)] 23215700K->15324301K(32097280K), 0.1232548 secs] [Times: user=0.70 sys=0.01, real=0.12 secs] 
35677.285: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8493736K->772444K(9616896K)] 23484049K->15762757K(31986688K), 0.1639453 secs] [Times: user=1.27 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs] 
35680.764: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8932188K->553685K(9745920K)] 23922501K->15543997K(32115712K), 0.1294150 secs] [Times: user=0.89 sys=0.01, real=0.13 secs] 
35684.199: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8804053K->867273K(9117696K)] 23794365K->15857586K(31487488K), 0.1873880 secs] [Times: user=1.31 sys=0.00, real=0.19 secs] 
35687.809: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9115716K->1159141K(9382400K)] 24106029K->16163478K(31752192K), 0.2832391 secs] [Times: user=1.76 sys=0.01, real=0.29 secs] 
35691.288: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9041381K->1305357K(9187840K)] 24045718K->16322144K(31557632K), 0.3632827 secs] [Times: user=2.19 sys=0.01, real=0.36 secs] 
35694.966: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9187597K->1337198K(9070080K)] 24204389K->16391907K(31439872K), 0.2874729 secs] [Times: user=2.04 sys=0.01, real=0.29 secs] 
35695.275: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 1397874K->1025280K(9216000K)] 16452582K->16408831K(31585792K), 0.2539362 secs] [Times: user=1.84 sys=0.02, real=0.25 secs] 
35698.760: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8272640K->1150789K(9151488K)] 23675376K->16558057K(31521280K), 0.2800219 secs] [Times: user=1.89 sys=0.02, real=0.28 secs] 
35699.180: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 1532509K->1257911K(8444928K)] 16939777K->16687262K(30814720K), 0.2502664 secs] [Times: user=1.81 sys=0.01, real=0.25 secs] 
35702.612: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 8444855K->2057201K(8287744K)] 23876741K->17717124K(30657536K), 0.4627608 secs] [Times: user=3.33 sys=0.01, real=0.46 secs] 
35705.765: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 8287729K->2316857K(8547840K)] 23973785K->18662968K(30917632K), 0.5713870 secs] [Times: user=4.35 sys=0.01, real=0.57 secs] 
35708.983: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 8547385K->1506000K(8211968K)] 24907890K->19799823K(30581760K), 0.7879174 secs] [Times: user=5.61 sys=0.05, real=0.78 secs] 
35712.170: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 7081168K->1507860K(8379904K)] 25385299K->20667366K(30749696K), 0.5480324 secs] [Times: user=3.84 sys=0.05, real=0.55 secs] 
35712.848: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 1827913K->78655K(8356352K)] 20987420K->20739404K(30726144K), 0.3986930 secs] [Times: user=2.84 sys=0.00, real=0.40 secs] 
35713.246: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 78655K->0K(8356352K)] [ParOldGen: 20660749K->3040778K(22369792K)] 20739404K->3040778K(30726144K), [Metaspace: 221552K->221548K(258048K)], 1.8512788 secs] [Times: user=11.76 sys=0.03, real=1.85 secs] 
35717.558: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5581312K->1725693K(7307264K)] 8661604K->4805985K(29677056K), 0.4301305 secs] [Times: user=2.80 sys=0.01, real=0.43 secs] 
35718.224: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 2387841K->238534K(8334848K)] 5468133K->5046571K(30704640K), 0.4111594 secs] [Times: user=3.21 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs] 
35721.064: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5701574K->1581940K(8312832K)] 10511283K->6596086K(30682624K), 0.3808009 secs] [Times: user=2.90 sys=0.00, real=0.38 secs] 
35721.784: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 2414567K->253910K(8349696K)] 7428713K->6850887K(30719488K), 0.4165103 secs] [Times: user=3.10 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs] 
35724.563: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 5734870K->1430285K(8315904K)] 12349610K->8265856K(30685696K), 0.3546620 secs] [Times: user=2.77 sys=0.01, real=0.35 secs] 
35727.261: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 6911245K->1478134K(8395776K)] 13756073K->9453169K(30765568K), 0.5245972 secs] [Times: user=4.10 sys=0.01, real=0.53 secs] 
35730.136: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7066614K->1547419K(8377344K)] 15070136K->10765885K(30747136K), 0.6109201 secs] [Times: user=4.32 sys=0.02, real=0.61 secs] 
35733.154: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7135899K->1315619K(8498176K)] 16389479K->11807006K(30867968K), 0.5097489 secs] [Times: user=4.01 sys=0.01, real=0.51 secs] 
35736.104: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 7027491K->1522542K(8398336K)] 17520210K->13137985K(30768128K), 0.5651593 secs] [Times: user=4.15 sys=0.01, real=0.56 secs] 
35736.689: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 1565298K->15164K(8409088K)] 13180742K->13160418K(30778880K), 0.3819311 secs] [Times: user=2.84 sys=0.00, real=0.38 secs] 
35739.429: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 5756220K->1578503K(7320064K)] 18901477K->14735846K(29689856K), 0.3715531 secs] [Times: user=2.64 sys=0.01, real=0.37 secs] 
35742.119: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7319559K->1281055K(8546816K)] 20496907K->15616628K(30916608K), 0.4926865 secs] [Times: user=3.79 sys=0.01, real=0.49 secs] 
35745.057: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7085087K->1579244K(8441856K)] 21431613K->17081234K(30811648K), 0.6018703 secs] [Times: user=4.32 sys=0.01, real=0.60 secs] 
35748.080: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7383276K->1613440K(8510976K)] 22885511K->18343626K(30880768K), 0.5818204 secs] [Times: user=4.48 sys=0.01, real=0.59 secs] 
35751.230: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7474304K->1472378K(8522752K)] 24261077K->19432841K(30892544K), 0.5637150 secs] [Times: user=4.17 sys=0.03, real=0.57 secs] 
35754.213: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7333242K->1598809K(8583680K)] 25293912K->20836636K(30953472K), 0.5915971 secs] [Times: user=4.50 sys=0.00, real=0.59 secs] 
35757.407: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7573849K->1375973K(8576000K)] 26838408K->21485227K(30945792K), 0.5083576 secs] [Times: user=3.55 sys=0.00, real=0.51 secs] 
35760.359: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7351013K->1586160K(8695808K)] 27465570K->22920840K(31065600K), 0.6046188 secs] [Times: user=4.46 sys=0.01, real=0.61 secs] 
35760.964: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 1586160K->0K(8695808K)] [ParOldGen: 21334680K->2921003K(22369792K)] 22920840K->2921003K(31065600K), [Metaspace: 221580K->221580K(258048K)], 1.6722028 secs] [Times: user=10.73 sys=0.01, real=1.67 secs] 
35765.327: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 6193664K->1833280K(8027136K)] 9114677K->4754294K(30396928K), 0.3855252 secs] [Times: user=2.90 sys=0.00, real=0.39 secs] 
35765.769: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 2003858K->73942K(8417792K)] 4924871K->4835980K(30787584K), 0.4092414 secs] [Times: user=3.19 sys=0.01, real=0.41 secs] 
35768.720: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 5931734K->1597340K(8521216K)] 10722102K->6443313K(30891008K), 0.3837882 secs] [Times: user=2.78 sys=0.01, real=0.39 secs] 
35769.136: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 1684805K->20953K(8378368K)] 6530777K->6471287K(30748160K), 0.3673869 secs] [Times: user=2.79 sys=0.01, real=0.37 secs] 
35771.996: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 5747673K->1547724K(8455680K)] 12211551K->8023474K(30825472K), 0.3499080 secs] [Times: user=2.52 sys=0.01, real=0.35 secs] 
35774.772: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 7274444K->1582035K(8476672K)] 13750198K->9392607K(30846464K), 0.5657404 secs] [Times: user=4.46 sys=0.01, real=0.56 secs] 
35777.830: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7342035K->1401068K(8467968K)] 15161539K->10378557K(30837760K), 0.5273704 secs] [Times: user=3.96 sys=0.01, real=0.53 secs] 
35780.768: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7161068K->1550240K(8588288K)] 16179376K->11479317K(30958080K), 0.5158061 secs] [Times: user=3.73 sys=0.01, real=0.52 secs] 
35783.874: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7516064K->1569631K(8562176K)] 17447661K->12875990K(30931968K), 0.5947770 secs] [Times: user=4.59 sys=0.01, real=0.59 secs] 
35787.030: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7535455K->1585147K(8636928K)] 18841965K->13976453K(31006720K), 0.5300475 secs] [Times: user=4.16 sys=0.01, real=0.53 secs] 
35790.192: [GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 7650299K->1456048K(8612864K)] 20050389K->14876764K(30982656K), 0.4947915 secs] [Times: user=3.81 sys=0.02, real=0.50 secs]
```

Which shows that GC is triggered mostly for allocation failures in the young gen.

**Update:** Here is Throughput evolution on the same time frame

[image]

Comment: What version of Java? From what vendor? Which garbage collector?

Comment: People start to wake up and use your service more actively? Can you show your load metric as well for this time?

Comment: @BasilBourque Java 8 and  Parallel GC

Comment: @Aivean updated with that info.

Comment: Post such details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think that under lighter load GC was using mostly [minor collections](https://dzone.com/articles/gc-explained-parallel-collector), cleaning only young and survivor spaces, while filling OldGen. At some point OldGen became full and major collection was performed, resulting the pause. At the same time GC goals were adjusted, which lead to GC using more CPU.

It's hard to match GC log timestamps to the chart times, you should try to enable pretty-printed dates in GC log with `-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`. But, as you can see, "Ergonomics" in `Full GC (Ergonomics)` indicates that [GC is adjusting its goals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html).

---

To summarize:

Parallel GC tries to maximize application throughput, setting collection goals and heap ratios. Under lighter load it may skip performing major GC. When load profile changes, GC behavior can also change (after some internal threshold is reached).

Comment: And how can I try to solve it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "solve"? If you want to avoid pauses, use different GC, that minimizes latency (parallel GC maximized throughput). If you want to avoid auto-tuning of GC goals, you can set these goals explicitly, but I warn you, unless you know what you're doing, there is a good chance that you'll hurt the performance.

Comment: What I'm trying to solve is that during that time the app response time was really bad. ¿Which type of GC would you recommend? Also this doesn't happen usually, is it possible that this is due to a memory leak?

Comment: I'd recommend [reading](https://dzone.com/articles/choosing-the-best-garbage-collection-algorithm-for) about all options and thinking what applies to your situation. G1 has a good default tradeoff between latency and throughput. ZGC has ultra small pauses, at the cost of 10-15% penalty to throughput. Parallel GC is mostly used for batch jobs, but you can try tuning its pause goal (`-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis`).

Comment: **"is it possible that this is due to a memory leak?"** — I don't think so, but you can make a heap dump and use memory analyzer to find out.